# Using PrincipalContext to ValidateCredentials fails with right password after sending many wrong passwords

Tags: validation, credentials, windows-identity, principalcontext

using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName))
{
   isWindowsAutenticated = pc.ValidateCredentials(username, password);
}

If pass to this code many wrong passwords for a user, then pass in the right password, it still returns false even though the password is definitely correct.

Any suggestions to get around this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It does matter what `username` you pass in:

1. joe
2. domain\joe
3. joe@domain.com

MSDN [does not specify it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb154889%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but my experience says the first one is the only correct and comparison is case insensitive.